# Interfaces: Java Language Specification

Tags: java, class, object, interface, abstract

[image: JLS Java SE 7 : 9.2]
Please explain:

1. 3rd bullet point
2. 5th line (in bold)
3. 2nd last line

Answer (score 2):

[Every class in Java is implicitly (or explicitly) a sub type of `java.lang.Object`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2)

> The class Object is a superclass (§8.1.4) of all other classes.

Because of this, you can invoke any method declared in `Object` on any variable of any class type.

```
String var = ...;
var.hashCode();
```

This has to be true for `interface` type variables as well

```
SomeInterface var = ...;
var.hashCode();
```

For this reason, the `interface` must implicitly declare (as `abstract`) those methods declared in `java.lang.Object`.

You can't override `final` methods, but an interface declares methods that must be implemented in sub types, so a compile time error will be thrown if the interface declares a method that is declared as `final` in `java.lang.Object`.

An interface can declare classes, interfaces, and fields in its body. If a sub interface declares any of those with the same name, then it is hiding those. It therefore doesn't inherit them.

For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Parent.answer);
    System.out.println(Child.answer);
}

interface Parent {
    int answer = 42;
}

interface Child extends Parent {
    int answer = 0;
}
```

prints

```
42
0
```

there is no way to get `Parent`'s value from a `Child` reference.